# Is it possible to use ribbon control in MVC4 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ribbon

I'm redesigning my Prism 4 WPF application into MVC 4 intranet application. In my old application I used Ribbon control. Is it possible to use Ribbon control in MVC application? Do you know about some existing implementations? I used only basic Ribbon features like buttons & check-boxes.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC does not use controls of any kind. Have you read the first thing about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to WPF, ASP.NET MVC doesn't use controls. It uses Models, Controllers and Views. Since the views are often HTML rendered by the browser you could use javascript and CSS to build such buttons. You may checkout the [jQuery Ribbon plugin](http://jqueryribbon.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Yes, this is something I'm looking for.